# box-sizing border appear on hover contents moving

Tags: html, css

code:

```
   <div class="block">

    </div>

div.block
{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
div.block:hover
{
   border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

When hovering the block with the use of box-sizing, the contents inside is moving, how to prevent this?

Comment: The border is pushed to the inside with `border-box`, so if it doesn't exist yet in initial stage, it will change the inners by those 1px borders.

Answer (score 8):

```
div.block {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid [your bg color];

}
div.block:hover {
   border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

Try this :)

When you hover it adds a border. So its making extra pixels. If you add a border to original item(this case block) IT wont have to add new pixels, as they already exsist.

As said below: border 1px solid transperparent wil work fine to

Comment: Or even: `1px solid transparent`.

Comment: @Hello please accept the answer if it satisfied your question's intend.

Answer (score 2):

Add padding and then remove equal to border pixels when hovering.

```
div.block
{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 10px;
}
div.block:hover
{
   border: 1px solid orange;
   padding: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about old IE versions better to try:

```
div.block:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px orange inset;
}
```

Or use the following

```
div.block {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}
div.block:hover {
   border-color:orange;
}
```